# Save output of python program in text file

Tags: python, text, output

I want to save the output of my Python program into a text file to use it in C for some reasons, I don't know how should I do it. The code is:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

t_start=0;t_end=1;dt=0.1
tpoints=np.arange(t_start,t_end,dt)
G = nx.grid_2d_graph(20,20, periodic=False, create_using=None)
adj_matrix=nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
print(adj_matrix.todense())
```

If the number of nodes were less than 20 (like 10 or lower) the output would be:

```
[[0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0]]
```

But when the number of nodes increase, the output is like this:

```
[[0 1 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 1 0]]
```

And so I can't copy it manually to a text file. So I need a command to write this matrix completely to a text file. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html this could be useful

Answer (score 0):

The displayed output of a numpy array is not meant to display everything.

If you want to save the array to a file, you can use `tofile`. There you can define if you want a binary or a text file.